# Java OCR isn't producing any output

Tags: java, ocr

I'm using this ocr algorithm http://sourceforge.net/projects/javaocr/ to detect numbers in an image. I've tried using tesseract, but i had the exact same problem, sometimes it didn't work. This hasn't ever worked (java ocr). When i used java ocr, it didn't procuce any output but /n.

The image is completely white and the numbers are black. The only artifacts in the image are two lines near the top and bottom borders that don't even interefere with the characters. The alignment is normal, like printed text, it's not handwriting or skewed.

```
BufferedImage image2 = ImageIO.read(new File("moneyImage"+".bmp"));
ImageManipulator.show(image2, 5);
OCRScanner scanner = new OCRScanner();
String items = scanner.scan(image2, 0, 0, 0, 0, null);
System.out.println(items);
```

The image2 shows clearly, and this example was taken from someone else that published it as such. I'm not doing anything complicated, and it doesn't make sense to me why this shouldn't work. It's a simple greyscale image.

When I try running the standalone program (the java ocr one), it works and produces the correct numbers as output. I don't know how to extract the characters from within my java project and why it doesn't work.

My test image is: [image: Test image]

Also, this

```
String lastText = null;
Tesseract instance = Tesseract.getInstance();
try {
    lastText = instance.doOCR(imageFile);
} catch (TesseractException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(ActionAbstraction.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

produces absolutely no output, even if i give a picture of a single digit, as outputted from java ocr. They seem to work but both just don't output anything when i do the actual scan.

Also, i'm using tiff images, and as I said before, the character extraction works normally. What doesn't work is java code calling a scan on the image. I have linked the appropriate libraries (or it would produce compiler errors)

Comment: how about sharing the image2 (imageshack maybe?)

Comment: Are you running is as a server process (web-app)? It could be the absence of the GUI.

Comment: it seems that it's a crappy open source project that nobody seems to care or maintain anymore. I could not find any doc or example either and it seems that (if you can make it work) you have to train your scanner first. Tesseract is not much better, but once I could make it work many years ago. My 2c

Answer (score 0):

Not sure: but aren't you telling the scanner just to look at top-left hand corner of your image with this line:

```
String items = scanner.scan(image2, 0, 0, 0, 0, null);
```

Maybe change it to (something like):

```
String items = scanner.scan(image2, 0, 0, 80, 20, null);
```

[change the 80,20 to whatever width/height your image is - you can probably get Java to do this for you - I think there is a method in the Image class if I remember correctly].

I got this (perhaps wrong) idea from doing a git clone of the source:

`git clone git://git.code.sf.net/p/javaocr/source javaocr-source`

And in the "javaocr-source\core\src\main\java" directory:
The interface contained in 'java.net.sourceforge.javaocr.ImageScanner.java' defines the 'scan' interface as follows:

//

```
void scan(
            Image image,
            DocumentScannerListener listener,
            int left,
            int top,
            int right,
            int bottom);
}
```

//

Comment: this is how this unit test did (http://code.google.com/r/oscarklee-javaocr/source/browse/plugins/awt/src/main/java/net/sourceforge/javaocr/ocrPlugins/OCRDemo/OCRScannerDemo.java?r=ae4c2b7589b3d75d9b5cc6d58452d57723fea932) although I am not sure if it's a compatible version

Comment: @Leo - you sure that is a genuine unit test ? It's in Maven's 'main' directory rather than 'test' - but assuming it is a test of somesort - it doesnt' seem to be trying to extract text - so maybe that was a delibrate test on a 0,0,0,0 image square ?, dunno.

Comment: I think this ocr lib is crappy. See the comments in their site. No one is maintaining it anymore

Answer (score 0):

This is the javadoc i found for the function scan into the source code of the project  :

```
 /**
 * Scan an image and return the decoded text.
 * @param image The <code>Image</code> to be scanned.
 * @param x1 The leftmost pixel position of the area to be scanned, or
 * <code>0</code> to start scanning at the left boundary of the image.
 * @param y1 The topmost pixel position of the area to be scanned, or
 * <code>0</code> to start scanning at the top boundary of the image.
 * @param x2 The rightmost pixel position of the area to be scanned, or
 * <code>0</code> to stop scanning at the right boundary of the image.
 * @param y2 The bottommost pixel position of the area to be scanned, or
 * <code>0</code> to stop scanning at the bottom boundary of the image.
 * @param acceptableChars An array of <code>CharacterRange</code> objects
 * representing the ranges of characters which are allowed to be decoded,
 * or <code>null</code> to not limit which characters can be decoded.
 * @return The decoded text.
 */
```

So

```
String items = scanner.scan(image2, 0, 0, 0, 0, null);
```

seems to be Ok according to the code documentation. However I tried it and it is not the case. This one of the worst documentations I have ever seen.